# When does introsort shift from quicksort to heapsort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, introsort

[Introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) begins with quicksort and switches to heapsort when the recursion depth exceeds a level based on the number of elements being sorted.  What is that number?  Is there a specific range or a limiting value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point at which the [Introsort algorithm](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~musser/gp/introsort.ps) switches from Quicksort to Heapsort is determined by *depth_limit*:

> *depth_limit* = 2 · ⎣log<sub>2</sub>(*l*)⎦

Where *l* is the length of the sequence that is to be sorted, so *l*‍=‍*n* for the whole sequence. With each recursive call *depth_limit* is decremented by one. When *depth_limit* reaches 0, it switches from Quicksort to Heapsort.

Comment: By your logic the Heapsort will never happen as the depth limit will never be reached.

Comment: @self. Why do you think so?

Comment: Read my comment below; another example: Array of 10000 members would have a depth limit of (13*2), if the array if approximately split in half on every recursion then on the 14th level the sub-arrays will have 0 elements.

Comment: @self. Well, splitting in half is the best-case; in worst-case the sequence will get split into (1,N-1). In that case depth_limit reaches 0.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried reading the introductory [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort). It says

> It counts the recursion depth. If a logarithmic depth is exceeded, the
>   algorithm switches to Heapsort from Quicksort to keep the worst case
>   outcome of Quicksort down

and through the Musser's original paper on Introsort.

> It says that introsort is slower than heapsort because it  performs
>   2*log(2,N) computations before it switches to heapsort.

My understanding is that recursion depth is 2*log(2,N)

> For N=300 elements to sort, it will be 2*8 = 16

Comment: If using depth limit of 16 on an arry of 300 elements at  approximately the 10th depth level the subarray will have 0 elements.