# In which situations is Quicksort faster than Bubblesort? Why?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, quicksort, bubble-sort

**Quicksort:**

```
void Quicksort(int array[], int left, int right){
     int pivot = left, i,ch,j;
     for(i=left+1;i<=right;i++){
         j = i;
         if(array[j] < array[pivot]){
          ch = array[j];
          while(j > pivot){
             array[j] = array[j-1];
             j--;
          }
          array[j] = ch;
          pivot++;
         }  
     }
     if(pivot-1 >= left){
         quick(array,left,pivot-1);
     }
     if(pivot+1 <= right){
         quick(array,pivot+1,right);
     }
  }
```

**Bubblesort:**

```
void Bubblesort(int array[])
{
    int length = array.length;
    int i,j,r,aux;
    for(i=length-1; i >= 1; i--) 
    {  
        for(j=0; j < i ; j++) 
        {
            if(array[j]>array[j+1]) 
            {
                aux = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    for(k = 0; k < length; ++k)
    {
        printf("%d\n",array[k]);
    }
}
```

**Worst case:**

Quicksort: n²

Bubblesort: n²

**Average case:**

Quicksort: nlog(n)

Bubblesort: n²

So usually, this means that Quicksort will tend to be faster than Bubblesort.

But in which situations is Quicksort faster than Bubblesort?

Remembering that when the list is in almost-sorted order already, Quicksort is going to keep recursing and for very small collections bubblesort can be faster.

Comment: It depends. For very small collections bubblesort can be faster,  but most of the the time quicksort will be quicker.

Comment: cross site dupe/related: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice.  Also you really should use google first.  Lots of information on this out there already.

Comment: Yes, and yes, quicksort can not always be relied upon, especially because of the choice of pivot.

Comment: "Is Quicksort faster than Bubblesort?" - for non-trivially sized sets to be sorted: **Yes** in *most* cases. But, in most situations, if sorting is not *the most* performance critical part of your application, you should probably just not worry too much and just use `std::sort` :)

Comment: Those big-O arguments only apply when *n* is large, so that any constant factors or overhead are swamped out. When *n* is small, the constant factors and overhead can dominate. Even among algorithms with the same big-O, the constant factors and overhead dominate. They don't bother mentioning that in classrooms. Also, that worst-case performance of quicksort is easily remedied by trivial changes.

Comment: I edited my question. Please, I would like the discussion to be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

> So usually, this means that Quicksort will tend to be faster than Bubblesort?

**Yes.** Much, much faster.

> Remembering that when the list is in almost-sorted order already, Quicksort is going to keep recursing.

**Right.** Quicksort's worst case is a big problem, so without modification it's not usually the algorithm of choice for real world use.

Comment: Re: point 2---But many of these 'edge-case' inefficiencies can be easily caught via a few simple changes to pure quicksort

Comment: @AlexW: [Introsort](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11175478/315052) for example.

Comment: @AlexW Edited to clarify. But it's common to just pick a different sort that avoids the problem, like heap sort.

Comment: Bubblesort will stop as soon as its done, making Bubblesort faster in such cases.

Comment: Quick Sort worst case will be`nlog(n)` if it is made sure that pivot will be selected in about middle of array.